# How to change document directory folder index number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I have created folder in document directory using **PGDataSource** class.

```
self.itmesDir = [self getDocumentPathForFileName: @"items"];

 -(NSString *) getDocumentPathForFileName: (NSString *) filename {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: filename];
}

-(NSString *) createFolderWithName: (NSString *) name {
NSString *folderPath = [self.itmesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: name];
[self.fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: folderPath withIntermediateDirectories: FALSE attributes:nil error: nil];
return folderPath;
}
```

This is my collection view datasource method.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

AlbumCollectionViewCell *cell = [_albumCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"albumCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//Label
NSString *folderName = [self.dataSource folderNameForIndex: (int)indexPath.row];
cell.albumTitleLabel.text = folderName;
//Sublabel
NSDictionary *_dicItem = [self.dataSource numberOfFilesForFolder:folderName];
int files = [self.dataSource numberOfFilesForDictionary:_dicItem];
NSString *folderDetails = [self.dataSource getPhotosStringFromNumber: _dicItem];
cell.albumDetailsLabel.text = folderDetails;  
return cell;
}
```

Here the method where i get the folder name,

```
-(NSString *) folderNameForIndex: (int) index {
NSArray *folderList = [self.fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: self.itmesDir error: nil];
return [folderList objectAtIndex: index];
}
```

I show the folders in a collection view. Now I can change the folder name but i need to change the position or index number of folder when i move the folder in collection view. How can i do that?

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with your question? You should be posting details about your data source for your collection view and code related to what you are having an issue with.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my question.